# Is there a way to get all available action_types?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-action-stats/#Reading
there is a field called action_type that can have different custom values(custom app events, pixel events) 
Is there any way to get list of all possible values for this field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just digging into that documentation there are two types of events that are associated with "action_type".

"App Events" (all available events): 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api/v2.8

"Facebook Pixel" (all available events); 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/conversion-tracking/v2.8